# Прелоад для ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

Есть функция, при нажатии на изображение, идет запрос и мы получаем новое изображение.
Но изображения разного размера и оно загружается и выглядит все не красиво. Как можно сделать прелоадер или чтобы изображение плавно появлялось?

Вот сама функция:

```
function nextPhoto() {  
        jQuery.ajax({url: "/guess_the_group/workphoto.php",
            dataType: "html",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(msg) {
                //alert("хуяк");
                document.getElementById('photoband').innerHTML = msg;
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Ошибка');
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Вот как оно работает http://yametal.net/guess_the_group/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто вы меняете хтмл в блоке и, видимо, его всегда видно. Сделайте пустой блок, скрытый, например. В него полученное через аякс добавляете `$("#идблока").append()` (перед этим отчистив его методом `$("#идблока").empty()`), добавляем ваш имейдж с параметром `onload="loadImage()",` а в функции делаем замену изображения отсюда со скрытого в открытый - это так, на вскидку вариант.

Answer (score 0):

.fadeOut(400)
.fadeIn(400)

> чтобы изображение плавно появлялось

Крутить нужно в этом направлении.